# Problema al guardar contraseña encriptada en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laragon

espero no molestar a nadie, solo quiero ver si me ayudan a resolver un error que tengo con php, estoy tratando de hacer una pequeña aplicación con php nativo, y he estoy teniendo un problema al hacer el signup del usuario, al momento que encripto la contraseña no me guarda los datos obtenidos del formulario, pero si no encripto la contraseña se guarda bien los datos no se que podría ser que lo este provocando, cabe aclarar que estoy trabajando la conexión de manera PDO. si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho :(

---

### INDEX.PHP

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT,['cost'=> 10]);

$querys->NewUser($name,$email,$hash);
```

---

### DATABASECONNECT.PHP

```
public function NewUser(string $name, string $email, string $password)
    {
    
        $insert = $this->conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO USUARIOS SET NOMBRE=?, EMAIL=?, PASSWORD=? ");

        $insert->execute([$name,$email,$password]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sin cifrar la contraseña si se guarda y cuando la cifras no la guarda, entonces puede ser la longitud de tu columna PASSWORD ya que al usar `password_hash` te genera un string de 60 caracteres por lo cual debes ampliar la longitud de tu columna.